# As much as - as many as

Tags: exam-questions, countability

Can anyone help me with this question about Error Identification.

> *As many as* 50 percent of the income from motion pictures *produced* in the United States *comes from*  the films *abroad*.

The key is "As many as". Explanation for this is that "As much as" should be used here because "income" is an uncountable noun. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

*Income* can be countable or uncountable depending on the context and use.

> > The salaries of both partners amounted to a substantial family income

or

> > Taking into consideration the incomes of the two brothers, the loan company agreed to give them a mortgage.

But this is beside the point because it's not income that's being compared but the percentage.

When talking about percentages, proportions or money in general, we use *much*

> > As much as 50%
> >
> > As much as half of what they earned
> >
> > As much as a million dollars

On the other hand, we use *many* when considering individual units:

> > As many as 50 parts in 100
> >
> > As many as a million dollar notes were printed that day.

Comment: You do everything except explain which one is correct in this specific sentence...

Comment: @Catija I thought *As much as 50%* did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Since your example is talking about an *amount*, 50% and not the *number*/*count* of income

> as much as

is correct.